# Getting wrong position on item click in listview

Tags: android, listview

**Pre-Conditions:-**

- I have a checkbox and two textviews in my listview.
- The size of my arraylist is 2 so two rows are being created.

Functionality:-
If i check the checkbox, the corresponding textviews will get enabled and hence they will become clickable.

This logic is working fine but the issue is that **if i check the 0th position checkbox, the 1st position textviews are getting enabled**

Another scenario is that even if the first checkbox when checked enabled the first textview only, on the textview's listener i am calling a date picker and setting date, but the date is set to the second textview

```
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if (rowView == null) {
      LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
      rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null);
      viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
      viewHolder.textview1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.TextView11);
      viewHolder.textview2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.TextView12);
      viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
      rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    }
    viewHolder.textview1.setEnabled(false) //default textview is false
    viewHolder.textview2.setEnabled(false) //default textview is false

    viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            if ( isChecked )
            {
                holder.textview1.setEnabled(true);
                holder.textview2.setEnabled(true);
            }
            else if ( !isChecked )
            {
                holder.textview1.setEnabled(false);
                holder.textview2.setEnabled(false);
            }

    }
});

// Textview's listeners here- showing toast in it. 
//When checking first checkbox, second position textviews are getting enabled

    return rowView;
  }
```

Here is my full custyom listview class :-

```
    package com.list.filter.datefilter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.exzeo.jarvis.ApplicationController;
import com.exzeo.jarvis.R;
import com.exzeo.jarvis.ui.DatePickerFragment;
import com.exzeo.jarvis.ui.DatePickerFragment.onDateSet;
import com.exzeo.jarvis.workards.list.filter.datefilter.model.AdvanceDateFilter;

public class AdvanceDateFilterList extends ListView{
    private boolean tabletSize = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);
    private CustomFilterAdapter dataAdapter = null;
    private Context context;
    private OnCheckChangedClickListener changedClickListener;

    public AdvanceDateFilterList(Context context, ArrayList<AdvanceDateFilter> filterArray) {
        super(context);
        this.context=context;
        displayListView((Activity) context, filterArray);
    }

    public void setOnCheckChangedClickListener(OnCheckChangedClickListener listener) {
        this.changedClickListener = listener;
    }

    public interface OnCheckChangedClickListener {
        public void onClick(ArrayList<AdvanceDateFilter> filter/*, int position*/); 
        //      public void onDateChange(AdvanceDateFilter filter, int position);
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(int id) {
        super.setId(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {

        //TODO:set height dynamic
        if (dataAdapter == null) {
            // pre-condition
            return;
        }

        int width = ApplicationController.getInstance().getDeviceWidth();
        int height = ApplicationController.getInstance().getDeviceHeight();

        if(height<width)
            height=width;

        int totalHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            totalHeight +=height/10;
        }
        if(totalHeight>(height/4))
            totalHeight=height/4;
        params.height = totalHeight + (this.getDividerHeight() * (dataAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        /*
        if(tabletSize){

        for (int i = 0; i < dataAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            totalHeight +=height/10;
        }
        if(totalHeight>(height/4))
            totalHeight=height/4;
        params.height = totalHeight + (this.getDividerHeight() * (dataAdapter.getCount() - 1));

        }else{
            for (int i = 0; i < dataAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                if(tabletSize)
                totalHeight +=height/25;
                else
                    totalHeight +=height/18;
            }
            if(totalHeight>(height/3))
                totalHeight=height/3;
            params.height = totalHeight + (this.getDividerHeight() * (dataAdapter.getCount() - 1));


        }*/
        params.width = -1;
//      params.height = -1;
        super.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
    private void displayListView(Activity activity, ArrayList<AdvanceDateFilter> filterArray) {

        dataAdapter = new CustomFilterAdapter(activity, context, R.layout.advance_date_filter_row, filterArray);
        setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    }

    private class CustomFilterAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AdvanceDateFilter> {

        private ArrayList<AdvanceDateFilter> filterList;
        private ViewHolder holder = null;
        private Activity activity;
        private int dateCheck = -1;
        FragmentManager fragmentManager;
        DatePickerFragment newFragment;
        public CustomFilterAdapter(Activity activity, Context context, int textViewResourceId,  ArrayList<AdvanceDateFilter> filterList) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, filterList);
            this.filterList = new ArrayList<AdvanceDateFilter>();
            this.filterList.addAll(filterList);
            this.activity=activity;
            fragmentManager =((Activity) context).getFragmentManager();
            newFragment = new DatePickerFragment(context);
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            CheckBox datefiltercheckbox;
            TextView fromDate, toDate;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return filterList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.advance_date_filter_row, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.fromDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fromdate);
                holder.toDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.todate);
                holder.datefiltercheckbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.datefiltercheckbox);
                convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.fromDate.setEnabled(false);
            holder.toDate.setEnabled(false);

            holder.fromDate.setText("From: "+filterList.get(position).getFromDate());
            holder.toDate.setText("To: "+filterList.get(position).getToDate());         

            if(filterList.get(position).getTypeOfDate().equals("WORKKARDLOSSDATEFILTER"))
                holder.datefiltercheckbox.setText("Loss Date");
            else if (filterList.get(position).getTypeOfDate().equals("WORKKARDREPORTEDDATEFILTER")) {
                holder.datefiltercheckbox.setText("Reported Date");
            }

            int checkBoxPaddingLeft = (int) (getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.rightDrawerFilterCheckbox)/getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
            holder.datefiltercheckbox.setPadding(checkBoxPaddingLeft, 0, 0, 0);

            holder.datefiltercheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
            holder.datefiltercheckbox.setChecked(filterList.get(position).isSelected());
            holder.datefiltercheckbox.setTag(filterList.get(position));

            if(filterList.get(position).isSelected()){
                holder.fromDate.setEnabled(true);
                holder.toDate.setEnabled(true);
                if(dateCheck == 0){
                    holder.fromDate.setText("From: "+filterList.get(position).getFromDate());
                }
                else{
                    holder.toDate.setText("To: "+filterList.get(position).getToDate());
                }

            }
            else{
                holder.fromDate.setEnabled(false);
                holder.toDate.setEnabled(false);
                if(dateCheck == 0){
                    holder.fromDate.setText("From: "+filterList.get(position).getFromDate());
                }
                else{
                    holder.toDate.setText("To: "+filterList.get(position).getToDate());
                }
            }
            newFragment.setDateListener(new onDateSet() {

                @Override
                public void onDate(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                    if(dateCheck == 0){
                        filterList.get(position).setFromDate(dayOfMonth+"/"+monthOfYear+"/"+year);
                        holder.fromDate.setText("From: "+filterList.get(position).getFromDate());

                    }
                    else{
                        filterList.get(position).setToDate(dayOfMonth+"/"+monthOfYear+"/"+year);
                        holder.toDate.setText("To: "+filterList.get(position).getToDate());
                    }

                    //              changedClickListener.onDateChange(filterList.get(position), position);
                    changedClickListener.onClick(filterList);
                }
            });


            holder.datefiltercheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if(isChecked){
                        holder.fromDate.setEnabled(true);
                        holder.toDate.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                    else{
                        holder.fromDate.setEnabled(false);
                        holder.toDate.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    filterList.get(position).setSelected(isChecked);

                    changedClickListener.onClick(filterList);

                }
            });

            holder.fromDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dateCheck = 0;
                    newFragment.show(fragmentManager, "datePicker");
                    newFragment.setDateRange(new Date(filterList.get(position).getFromDate()).getTime(), 
                            new Date(filterList.get(position).getToDate()).getTime());


                }
            });

            holder.toDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dateCheck = 1;
                    newFragment.show(fragmentManager, "datePicker");
                    newFragment.setDateRange(new Date(filterList.get(position).getFromDate()).getTime(), 
                            new Date(filterList.get(position).getToDate()).getTime());
                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @RajeshCP - No, it didn't. Still researching the issue

Comment: What is the issue have you tried the code I gave ?

Comment: I have modified my question and added the full class.

Comment: Another scenario is that even if the first checkbox when checked enabled the first textview only, on the textview's listener i am calling a date picker and setting date, but the date is set to the second textview

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this excellent tutorial on adding multiple clickable views in a list item.
The main culprit of your problem is probably listview recycling. Have a look at this:

http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/11/23/listview-tips-tricks-4-add-several-clickable-areas/

Answer (score 0):

As you said in your answer, the views are recycling by android since the inflating operation makes an intense use of CPU, so doing that, android try to reduce the amount of inflating operation.
I don't really think that assume that rowView is null is a good idea at all. What I think you have to do is, in the onChange listener, check if the rowView that contains the text you are going to change is the same that it should be, otherwise you don't need to change that text because the view has been recycled and is not visible anymore. When the adapter requires the view again, the text view will be set properly.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that you're setting both checkbox as checked on the interface `onCheckedChanged()`, there's one parameter that you can use to see which one was pressed:

```
viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if ( isChecked )
        {  
          switch(buttonView.getId()){
           case R.id.checkbox1:
           holder.textview1.setEnabled(true);                 
           break;
           case R.id.checkbox2:
           holder.textview2.setEnabled(true);                
           break;
          }
        }
        else if ( !isChecked )
        {
            holder.textview1.setEnabled(false);
            holder.textview2.setEnabled(false);
        }
}
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I've already got that issue. I've because the views are reused by the system or something.

Just force `if (rowView == null)` to be `true`. I mean change

```
if (rowView == null) {
  LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
  rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null);
  viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
  viewHolder.textview1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.TextView11);
  viewHolder.textview2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.TextView12);
  viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
  rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
}
else{
    holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
}
```

to

```
  LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
  rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null);
  viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
  viewHolder.textview1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.TextView11);
  viewHolder.textview2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.TextView12);
  viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
  rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
```

Comment: So like if my `getCount` returns 100, then 100 objects will be created and reusable holder pattern will not work

Comment: This is bad because it will cause memory lack, and listview will scroll slowly and laggy if there're alot items in the adapter :-/

Comment: I haven't found yet another way to solve this kind of problem. If you know something, please share it. I do think it could help a bunch of people.

Comment: I know, don't feel bad, the problem is that you're "helping" other people with the same kind of problem, but you aren't really helping, you're covering the issue with a bad "cover" that's the problem, also there alot tutorials, and even from Google (Google I/O) that they show how to avoid this kind of problem you're showing as answer.

Comment: Please guide me to tutorials handling the problem i posted above. I didn't downvote you

Comment: You mean how to make an effective adapter?